# Trying to update the managed reference registry with invalid propertyPath

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have got this error while running my project: `Trying to update the managed reference registry with invalid propertyPath(likely caused by a missing reference instance)'managedReferences[5133702300286058497].value', with value '2'` in Unity 2021.3.9f1 Personal.

I have no clue what causes it and the error doesn't link to any of my scripts (or anything at all).
It happens only when I click on the run button and the project still works normally after unpausing it.
Does anybody know where to look to fix it (I checked the last properties I added) or what may cause it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I still don't what really caused this error but I managed to fix it.
After discovering that `propertyPath` is a method of `SerializedProperty`, I tried to force the reserialization of my objects.

The fix was simply to remove the main script of my project containing lots of parameters I set through the inspector (I use `OdinInspector`) and recreate it.